# Search (and select) features in a shapefile that contain multiple strings using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, search

I want find (and possibly select) all features from a multi-polygon that contain the names 'Angelica' and 'Anthoxanthum' in the attribute table.
In this case it would be feature 1 and 6.

Is there a way to do it with a SQL query or some other tool?

I tried the 'Find tool' and the 'Select by Attribute' tool but my attribute table contains hundreds of columns.

[image]

The goal is to find (and select) every feature in which the two names 'Angelica' and Anthoxanthum' occur.

Update:
As suggested by @ycartwhelen and @FelixIP

```
    import arcpy
        
    fc = 'D:/data/myshpefile'
    fields = ['_Art_1', '_Art_2', '_Art_3']
            
    set2test = set(['Pfeifengras','Herzblatt']) 
    def queryMany(listOfSents):   bigSet = set()   

for s in listOfSents:  
   bigSet.update(set(s.split(" ")))   
   return not len(set2test.difference(bigSet))  
    
    queryMany([ !_Art_1!,    !_Art_2!,  !_Art_3!,   (.....)     !_Art_82!])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a python script which uses a loop and [search cursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to iterate through all your features. The search cursor could return all the attributes for a given feature as a list, and then you could use an if statement to check if your string is in the list (if "angelica" in attr_list: do something).

Where the if statement evaluates true you have a couple options. One would be to use an insert cursor to build a new feature layer of the "selected" features. Another would be to store the object IDs in a list, and then after the loop is complete do a Select by Attribute based where object ID is in that list of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function below in your script as you iterate through records. It returns True if both words found:

```
set2test = set(['rabbit','puppy'])

def queryMany(listOfSents):
  bigSet = set()
  for s in listOfSents:  bigSet.update(set(s.split(" ")))
  return not len(set2test.difference(bigSet))
```

#----------------

```
queryMany([ !A!, !B!, !C!])
```

[image]

Function creates a set of words from multiple fields and checks if both of interest are present.

Don't forget to include OID@ field in your cursor. This way you can append initially empty list and apply layer.setSelectionSet method to trigger selection.

[CREDITS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938804/generate-random-sentences-in-python)